# jquery extract values from css

Tags: jquery

How do I extract a style property

```
<div id="clipProperty" style="clip: rect(0px 281px 647px 0px);"></div>
```

and append it to # getClipVaalues with 30 subtracted from the the second value 281, so it says clip: rect(0px 251px 647px 0px) ?

```
 <div id="getClipValues"></div>
```

This is my js code

```
var clipProperty = $('#clipProperty').attr('style');
$('#getClipValues').attr('style', clipProperty);
```

The property of clipProperty is not constant, but changes regularly. But I always need to subtract 30 from the second value.

Comment: "Want to..." is not a question.  Can you add an actual question?  With a question mark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do it:

```
var re = /rect\((\d+)px (\d+)px (\d+)px (\d+)px\)/;
var oldClip = $('#clipProperty').css('clip');
var newClipVal = oldClip.replace(re, "$2");
$('#getClipValues').css('clip','rect(0px '+(newClipVal-30)+'px 647px 0px)');
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, the value of #clipProperty is not constant so I need to calculate whatever oldClip is.

Comment: it is not working in IE 10. newClipVal is returning  rect(0px, 766px, 842px, 0px) in stead of just 766px. Do you know why?

Comment: Other than IE being a steaming pike of turd, no. Seems to have something to do with the replace(). Looks like IE separates the values with commas while everyone else uses spaces. Looking into a fix.

Comment: Try changing the first line to `var re = /rect\((\d+)px,* (\d+)px,* (\d+)px,* (\d+)px\)/;`. Worked for me in IE10.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
var clip = $('#clipProperty').attr('style'); 

var clip2 = $('#getClipValues').css('clip', 'rect(0px 231px 647px 0px');
```

I made a little jsFiddle with it to get a result: http://jsfiddle.net/jtu5y1te/1/